# How to parse nested optional tokens in macro_rules?

Tags: rust, macros, macro-rules

When trying to do

```
macro_rules! tipey {
    (Vec<$pt: tt>) => { 2 };
    (Vec<Option<$pt: tt>>) => { 3 };
    ($pt: tt) => { 1 };
}

macro_rules! structy {
    (struct $i: ident { 
        $($p: ident: $pt: tt $(<$ppt: tt $(<$gt: tt> )? > )?),+
        $(,)?
    }) => {
        const v: &[usize] = &[ $(tipey!( $pt $(<$ppt $(<$gt>)?>)?)),+ ];
    };
}

structy!(
    struct ContentDetails {
        pattern: String,
        fields: Vec<Option<String>>,
    }
);
```

I get

[image: no rules expected the token >>]

How do I make this parse?

Comment: Converted both `>>` to `> >`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aa956e5c967b66f6140997e88088f8e9 Not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: omg you are right. this becomes a single token

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by your indiscriminate use of `tt` in your macros. This should be a last resort, as it can essentially match *anything*. The Rust compiler must disambiguate `>>` as part of a type v.s. expression based on the expected syntax. If you expect *anything*, then Rust must interpret `>>` as an operator.

Choose more appropriate [metavariables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#metavariables) such as `ty` (type), `ident` (identifier), `path` (fully specified path), etc.

Comment: Yeah but I want to be able to match against Vec<tt> and Vec<Option<tt>> and there is no way to split ty later